# Como verificar se conectou no banco de Dados?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

como verifico se meu código **PHP + PDO** conectou com sucesso ao banco de dados **MySQL**?

Com o código assim ele funciona:

```
<?php
/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=bancoservico';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$opcoes = array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                 PDO::ATTR_CASE       => PDO::CASE_UPPER    
    );

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $opcoes);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

O erro se dá quando o código está assim:

```
<?php

class AcessoDados {

public function __construct(){
   $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=bancoservico';
   $user = 'root';
   $password = '';
   $opcoes = array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                 PDO::ATTR_CASE       => PDO::CASE_UPPER    
        );

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $opcoes);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }       
  }
}
```

Link para teste:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4382d8813f699766f41658ce9f3101867eb8fd36

Comment: Talvez ajude: [PDO Connection Test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263443)

Comment: O jeito é criar a conexão como tem na documentação (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) e no final dá um echo na variável que armazena a conexão , na documentação diz que se ocorrer com sucesso a variável retornará um objeto PDO. Tenta assim.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta...

Comment: Que erro? não entendi.

Comment: Você instanciou a classe `$conn = new AcessoDados();` primeiramente? [exemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1d1f43f59f4c81cfa3936ae1614f08a725c4cc1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graças a ajuda do camarada [Tiago NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/155256/8939) eu montei este script com técnicas de segurança e totalmente funcional para você, venho aperfeiçoando a forma como me conecto ao meu banco de dados de tempo em tempo e hoje acho interessante utilizar desta forma e agora com a atualização da ajuda mencionada.

```
<?php class query_sql {
    protected static $conect;
    private function __construct() {

        $mysql_host = "";
        $mysql_base = "";
        $mysql_user = "";
        $mysql_pass = "";

        try { self::$conect = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $mysql_host . "; dbname=" . $mysql_base, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
            self::$conect -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$conect -> exec("set names utf8");
            $conect = null; }

        catch(PDOException $error) {
            echo $error -> getMessage(); } }

    public static function conect_sql() {
        if (!self::$conect) {
            new query_sql; }
        return self::$conect; } }

    $bind_sql = query_sql::conect_sql(); ?>

<?php $list_information = $bind_sql -> prepare("SELECT user_email, user_name FROM usuarios WHERE user_email = :user_email LIMIT 1");
    $list_information -> bindValue(":user_email", "@");
    $list_information -> execute();
    $list_information = $list_information -> fetchAll(); ?>

<?php foreach($list_information as $list_information) {
    echo $list_information["user_email"] . " | " . $list_information["user_name"]; } ?>

<?php $compare_information = $bind_sql -> prepare("SELECT user_email, user_pass FROM usuarios WHERE user_email = :user_email AND user_pass = :user_pass LIMIT 1");
    $statement_array = array(":user_email" => "@", ":user_pass" => "pass");
    foreach($statement_array as $array_key => $array_value) {
        $compare_information -> bindValue($array_key, $array_value); }
    $compare_information -> execute();
    $compare_information = $compare_information -> fetchAll(); ?>

<?php foreach($compare_information as $compare_information) {
    echo $compare_information["user_email"]; } ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php

class Acesso{
    protected static $db; 
    private function __construct(){
    $db_host = "<nome do host>";
    $db_database = "<nome do banco de dados>";
    $db_usuario = "<nome do usuario>";
    $db_senha = "<senha do usuario>";
    $db_driver = "mysql";

        try{
            self::$db = new PDO("$db_driver:host=$db_host; dbname=$db_database", $db_usuario, $db_senha);
            # Permite ao PDO lançar exceções durante erros.
            self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            # Dados armazenados com codificação UTF-8 caso deseje assim
            self::$db->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {            
             # Parar carregamento da página
             die("Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
     }

        public static function conexao(){
            if (!self::$db)
            {
                new Acesso;
            }
            return self::$db;
        }
    }
}
```

Salve como **pdo.class.php** ou qualquer outro nome

Para usar:

```
  <?php

  include("pdo.class.php");      

  $pdo = Acesso::conexao();
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabela'); -> tabela = nome da tabela
```

Answer (score 4):

Amigo, talvez você queira algo como:

```
<?php

//hide/show errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class AcessoDados {
public $conn;

public function _construct(){
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=bancoservico';
    $usuario = 'root';
    $senha = '';
    $opcoes = array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                     PDO::ATTR_CASE       => PDO::CASE_UPPER    
        );

    try{
        $this -> conn = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $senha, $opcoes);
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        die('Não foi possível conectar: ' . mysql_error());
    }        
  }
}
```

Lembrando que você pode habilitar o código:

```
//hide/show errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

onde o 1 é para você Mostrar os erros que geram caso ele não se conecte! Para esconder os erros mude para 0.

Comment: Estou acessando http://localhost/ControleServicos/AcessoDados/AcessoDados.php , mas não aparece nada na página.

Comment: Então talvez seja pq ele conectou!   
  
Tente adicionar no bloco que faz a conexao: echo "conexao com sucesso";

Comment: Coloquei antes do Try e depois, mas ele o echo não aparece, estou duvidando que meu código está sendo executado.

Comment: @J.C.Galhardi Só uma tela branca pode dizer que existe um erro que não está sendo reportado **antes** de cair no try. Veja a sessão Erros comum na tag do [tag:php]

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta...